# What are the drawbacks of using Cloud Jira

Tags: cloud, jira, jira-plugin

My company is evaluating Cloud Jira. What are the drawbacks of using Cloud Jira. 
I have got a comment from a colleague that E-signature plugin and E-signature extract tool are not compatible with cloud JIRA. What are its implication.

Answer (score 0):

The two main differences are:

1. on cloud you cannot customize JIRA as much as JIRA on premise.
2. the JIRA plugins MAY be available for both JIRA cloud and on premise but you should check it by yourself on their marketplace depending on the plugins you need.

Regarding E-Signature plugin, it is not available on the cloud version and IMHO you can't do anything about that.